# Change multiple properties at once in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I have this JSON object :

```
[ 
            {
                "nodeId" : "eb7224e6-f108-e3ec-7af2-3e76c6ab60b4",
                "nodeText" : "Présentation",
                "hasChildren" : null
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "d12125ed-9691-7088-284e-866b8e152496",
                "nodeText" : "Nouveautés V6",
                "count" : 2
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "a53e8858-1251-4429-82ae-b5f476872983",
                "nodeText" : "Pré-requis",
                "count" : 0,
                "hasChildren" : null
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "d395e444-dc8f-1efc-4afd-b1c130298c6c",
                "nodeText" : "Installation",
                "hasChildren" : null
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "f331b3d1-55c6-9d88-faf6-9a2e9127d765",
                "nodeText" : "Déploiement",
                "hasChildren" : true,
                "selected" : true
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "2293ed8b-8624-3e5b-e2dc-7610743cbb11",
                "nodeText" : "Utilisation depuis un PC",
                "hasChildren" : null
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "17deb2c8-80d6-d541-f435-1020f83e52bc",
                "nodeText" : "Utilisation depuis un MFP"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "a8188c37-57f6-774d-1d83-5eb5754d185f",
                "nodeText" : "{#DocTitle#} depuis la zone de notification",
                "hasChildren" : true
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "56650c51-8a74-3eec-832d-bf8298ce551b",
                "nodeText" : "Copie fidèle (option)",
                "hasChildren" : null
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "825aa19c-4e89-72ca-7118-b91447bc7fed",
                "nodeText" : "Création de dossiers automatiquement",
                "hasChildren" : true
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "33d61245-dcb9-65e6-d798-a08198a157ab",
                "nodeText" : "Compagnies",
                "hasChildren" : null
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "bdc8e226-90b4-c0ca-b6ca-724070a6360e",
                "nodeText" : "Application mobile"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "c17ebda9-6c7a-d554-ec14-77de4fe64585",
                "nodeText" : "Modèles de zones",
                "hasChildren" : null
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "71c4e09e-7e5b-0661-69c8-a16d89584f04",
                "nodeText" : "HotFolders"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "92a80f73-f855-a653-1c29-d0a8d39fb9be",
                "nodeText" : "Se connecter au cloud"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "aab9371b-efa0-26c3-5e10-7046e3b3a350",
                "nodeText" : "{#PRODUCT_NAME_ALERTER#}"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "765e1169-faa3-1f30-9bdb-0a3ab08a4c9c",
                "nodeText" : "Mise à jour"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "cf546983-c7f8-34e8-2285-80259f9da523",
                "nodeText" : "Sauvegarde"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "bab5f1ea-2ac2-dd85-70d1-7130d32fbcac",
                "nodeText" : "Transférer la licence"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "fe383237-110f-5b06-bd5d-1c33215c449a",
                "nodeText" : "Connecteurs métiers"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "4436d3c8-ed22-50a1-5846-b34598bac9c2",
                "nodeText" : "Fichier .lck"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "a024df3d-9d6b-335f-39da-9e08cbfb5d39",
                "nodeText" : "Mode démo"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "7151e70d-a40e-5a53-ecee-72382bc8100a",
                "nodeText" : "Personnalisation de l'interface web",
                "hasChildren" : null
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "52276de4-be31-21af-67a3-304560a00076",
                "nodeText" : "<include (skyged.paperswap.io)/> Versions"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "5ce2d985-9ea9-3135-b5cd-16b6d36e17a6",
                "nodeText" : "A quoi sert Quickstore ?",
                "parentID" : "e9c2b2a4-4583-eff9-d0de-bc4d7d2bf50f"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "b74f21bc-ea5a-3589-efe6-fe0941d67e2b",
                "nodeText" : "Nouveautés",
                "parentID" : "e9c2b2a4-4583-eff9-d0de-bc4d7d2bf50f"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "c2e34c9a-d21b-6b47-073f-6c57e47ce7a1",
                "nodeText" : "Pré-requis",
                "hasChildren" : null,
                "parentID" : "e9c2b2a4-4583-eff9-d0de-bc4d7d2bf50f",
                "count" : 0
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "4b670c23-c571-09fe-1f47-3f6a10d1252d",
                "nodeText" : "Contact",
                "parentID" : "e9c2b2a4-4583-eff9-d0de-bc4d7d2bf50f"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "4815568e-e1ce-1699-8685-b0c5290c336e",
                "nodeText" : "Téléchargement",
                "parentID" : "be225e39-9848-913a-1b18-0f3995e2199a"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "31d705d3-12ec-fc8f-2f56-ab27ba62842d",
                "nodeText" : "Installation sur un PC",
                "parentID" : "be225e39-9848-913a-1b18-0f3995e2199a"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "937a895e-2ddd-5778-43bc-746bd5542b52",
                "nodeText" : "Présentation",
                "parentID" : "258f80bf-e03e-37d1-24b9-4b60d367fce8"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "27d1f371-b6eb-cbec-4787-180be322058a",
                "nodeText" : "Déploiement",
                "parentID" : "258f80bf-e03e-37d1-24b9-4b60d367fce8"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "efea42be-fd52-e217-57a7-d2c45bcbd891",
                "nodeText" : "MFP",
                "parentID" : "e6451573-54a0-c4e9-3865-b5cc91b46c2c"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "1f5d5bac-0859-308f-fff3-d4ca2e988936",
                "nodeText" : "Fuji 7100A",
                "parentID" : "e6451573-54a0-c4e9-3865-b5cc91b46c2c",
                "hasChildren" : true
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "c9aa9f7a-06ff-ee79-5763-c16b93a10616",
                "nodeText" : "Création automatique de dossier",
                "parentID" : "efcd8b91-d3b9-24ca-0624-18afa8ac4901"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "87187ab4-fc76-fbcb-af42-ed152cc8dcd3",
                "nodeText" : "Compagnies",
                "parentID" : "efcd8b91-d3b9-24ca-0624-18afa8ac4901"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "32b05050-cb26-55a3-a85e-862b609f0488",
                "nodeText" : "Modèles de zones",
                "parentID" : "efcd8b91-d3b9-24ca-0624-18afa8ac4901"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "a2695284-0f88-d25f-beca-6871f04835ed",
                "nodeText" : "Mise à jour",
                "hasChildren" : null,
                "parentID" : "c83b648c-5f65-47b8-ba9d-7e272aca4ccd"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "d261ac75-8479-2f08-161a-af03517610b7",
                "nodeText" : "Sauvegarde",
                "hasChildren" : null,
                "parentID" : "c83b648c-5f65-47b8-ba9d-7e272aca4ccd"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "54a37067-4131-62b9-b78d-7c3914f1fe2f",
                "nodeText" : "Logs",
                "hasChildren" : null,
                "parentID" : "c83b648c-5f65-47b8-ba9d-7e272aca4ccd"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "4466c85b-7c01-f455-dfb9-a5cac1776661",
                "nodeText" : "Générer le classement",
                "parentID" : "330c28f1-7f74-d8c6-da62-8b81044c779c"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "76142336-302f-9a8b-9088-c0c5f467e4b9",
                "nodeText" : "QuickNote",
                "parentID" : "330c28f1-7f74-d8c6-da62-8b81044c779c"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "f2c630fa-5a10-7161-92d9-1b41e00279a1",
                "nodeText" : "Scanner dans ce dossier",
                "parentID" : "330c28f1-7f74-d8c6-da62-8b81044c779c"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "0e7222ae-e828-aa02-518b-d24bb927e4f3",
                "nodeText" : "Partager le dossier",
                "parentID" : "330c28f1-7f74-d8c6-da62-8b81044c779c"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "b791bd01-2f33-89f1-df1f-19df39eb9baf",
                "nodeText" : "Classer",
                "parentID" : "330c28f1-7f74-d8c6-da62-8b81044c779c"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "880dd1f3-fd4a-0a12-6f96-517559f22286",
                "nodeText" : "Editeur PDF",
                "parentID" : "330c28f1-7f74-d8c6-da62-8b81044c779c"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "9744404b-f9e0-5ad4-55cd-4880b3078e08",
                "nodeText" : "Envoyer dans le panier",
                "parentID" : "330c28f1-7f74-d8c6-da62-8b81044c779c"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "0b15de47-825c-1cce-3ba7-6eb67360d30d",
                "nodeText" : "Copie fidèle",
                "parentID" : "330c28f1-7f74-d8c6-da62-8b81044c779c"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "f3b7c8ab-5c4f-1951-0898-bd5fc3ca9741",
                "nodeText" : "Multi-comptes",
                "parentID" : "a8188c37-57f6-774d-1d83-5eb5754d185f"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "5a2a17c0-e31b-32bc-edfe-6411a0e2c2df",
                "nodeText" : "Paramètres",
                "parentID" : "a8188c37-57f6-774d-1d83-5eb5754d185f",
                "hasChildren" : null
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "b7a30436-241a-a50e-2856-0ab06a9af904",
                "nodeText" : "Profils",
                "parentID" : "a8188c37-57f6-774d-1d83-5eb5754d185f",
                "hasChildren" : null
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "4802e730-e90c-1f84-5785-10312a01e8e1",
                "nodeText" : "Fuji 7100A",
                "parentID" : "f331b3d1-55c6-9d88-faf6-9a2e9127d765",
                "hasChildren" : null
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "0a139fba-b6e2-a524-9fba-b9b88586b415",
                "nodeText" : "HP",
                "parentID" : "f331b3d1-55c6-9d88-faf6-9a2e9127d765"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "ed3d329b-7ceb-1099-109f-cee1112c14c3",
                "nodeText" : "Kyocera",
                "parentID" : "f331b3d1-55c6-9d88-faf6-9a2e9127d765",
                "hasChildren" : null
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "e5374df0-dfd0-c942-3bd4-d4a4bbe00c4b",
                "nodeText" : "Ricoh",
                "parentID" : "f331b3d1-55c6-9d88-faf6-9a2e9127d765",
                "hasChildren" : null
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "fd5badef-3943-325b-f038-8ab9c63486d6",
                "nodeText" : "Sharp",
                "parentID" : "f331b3d1-55c6-9d88-faf6-9a2e9127d765",
                "hasChildren" : null
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "231792f9-f90a-dcca-e8c4-8a1657f0a0c1",
                "nodeText" : "Toshiba",
                "parentID" : "f331b3d1-55c6-9d88-faf6-9a2e9127d765"
            }, 
            {
                "nodeId" : "8e0fe0bd-7615-1ff5-f801-93477bb34170",
                "nodeText" : "XEROX",
                "parentID" : "f331b3d1-55c6-9d88-faf6-9a2e9127d765"
            }
        ]
```

The issue is that some object have a `parentID` field that equals to another object's `nodeId`, I want to change the `nodeID` of an object while also the corresponding `parentID` of another object.

Here is my solution but I can't figure out a way to change the `parentID` field of the objects to match the newly changed `nodeID`:

```
function newID() {
  function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
      .toString(16)
      .substring(1);
  }
  return (
    s4() +
    s4() +
    '-' +
    s4() +
    '-' +
    s4() +
    '-' +
    s4() +
    '-' +
    s4() +
    s4() +
    s4()
  );
}

oldMenu.menu.forEach(function(item, index){
            let newid = newID();
            //...

            item.nodeId = newid;
          });
```

Comment: Can you provide an example with a dataset?

Comment: Can you update the example what you want to achieve??

Comment: @Rajasekar The dataset is the JSON object above bro

Comment: Yeah, Can you give a example input and output.

Answer (score 0):

```
   let dupArr = [];
   oldMenu.menu.forEach(function(item, index){
        let newid = newID();
        let dupObj = item;
        let index = oldMenu.findIndex((a) => a.parentID === item.nodeId);
        if(index > -1) { //if nodeId is equal with some ParentID, it will replace with newID
          dupObj.nodeId = newid; 
        }
        dupArr.push(dupObj)
      });
  console.log(dupArr) //you will get updated Arr.
```

Comment: And what about the `parentID` of the other objects?

Comment: If NodeID is equal with parentID, it will replace to new ID

Answer (score 0):

Here are two methods, the first with a higher complexity (N * N) without modifying your data set

```
oldMenu.menu.forEach(function(item, index) {

        let newid = newID();

        oldMenu.menu.forEach(function(oItem, oIndex) {
            if (oItem.parentID === item.nodeId) {
                oItem.parentID = newid;
            }
        });

        item.nodeId = newid;
})
```

The second with a lower complexity (N * 4) but modifying your data set

```
let perNodeId = {};

oldMenu.menu.forEach(function(item, index) {
    perNodeId[item.nodeId] = item;
})

oldMenu.menu.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if (typeof item.parentID !== 'undefined') {
        item.parentNode = perNodeId[item.parentID];
    }
})

oldMenu.menu.forEach(function(item, index) {
    let newid = newID();
    item.nodeId = newid;
})

oldMenu.menu.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if (typeof item.parentID !== 'undefined') {
        item.parentID = item.parentNode.nodeId;
    }
})
```

I don't think you can do it "at once"